# How to get the active tab in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have tabs inside a modal with this code:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive tabs-top">

<ion-tab title="FIND">
<ion-view>
<ion-content>
<div class="list list-inset">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.sight" placeholder="Find events or people" ng-change="searchSight()">
  </label>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
</ion-tab>
<ion-tab>
   ... More tabs
</ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And I have a footer button that I want to perform a particular action according to the active tab, **How do I get the active tab in Ionic?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the selected index of your tab using the $ionicTabsDelegate, which could possibly help you determine what action to take.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicTabsDelegate) {
         if ($ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex() == 0){
     // Perform some action 
    }
}
```

Use the $getByHandle method to control specific ionTabs instances.

Example:

```
$ionicTabsDelegate.$getByHandle('my-handle').selectedIndex();
```

Explained in further detail at the [$ionicTabsDelegate API Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicTabsDelegate/)

Comment: I do not understant but i alway get false

Comment: Try this, in an app with multiple tabs. This should list the tab number in console log, each time you call the function.  function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicTabsDelegate) {
        console.log ($ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex())
}

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Ionic uses ui-router. To get the current state in UI-router, you can use the $state directive described in ui-router's [API documentation here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

The 2 methods that might interest you are probably:

```
$state.is('state-name');
$state.includes('part-of-state-name-');
```

You'll need to make sure that you have $state injected into the footer's controller if you want to reference it directly in the html, or you can define a scope method or variable if you want to take that logic off the controller.

Comment: Not sure this will help if your tabs are inside the same state though.